# ¿Porque me aparece ese error y como puedo solucionarlo? django:Error during template rendering

Tags: python, django-views, django-templates

[image]
Después de haber cambiado el nombre de la app por "gestionAcademica" me aparece este error en el **view**, pero antes esto no sucedía, y todo cargaba correctamente

[image]

De esta forma se ve el **view** y ya relacione (importe) el **models** al **view**, no entiendo porque sucede ese error

Comment: l código siempre como texto, con formato. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Además, puedes adjuntar un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) en la pregunta como snippet (con el botón que indica <>). Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) y haz el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Puede que necesites crear y correr las migraciones para crear las tablas.